# Java логика алгоритма, инициализация массива

Tags: массивы, java

добрый вечер(ночь/утро). Не могу понять, каким образом построена логика, и почему программа не выдаёт мне то, что я хочу. во-первых - почему в i-ю ячейку массива "а" не записывается текущее значение i, и во-вторых - почему значение "7" записано во вторую ячейку, а не в третью (разве отсчет не с нуля идет?) код прилагаю.

```
public static void my_while()   
    {
            int a[];
            a = new int[5]; // в массиве "а" пять ячеек
            int i = 0;
            while(i<4) // то есть четыре раза: i=0, i=1, i=2, i=3
            {
                a[i] = 5; //в a[0], a[1], a[2] a[3] при каждой итерации
                //записывается по пятёрке
                a[3] = 7; // в a[3] записывается семерка
                i++;
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            }   
        }
    }
```

результат выполнения программы:
0 0 7 0. Я же ожидала, что будет "5 5 5 7". что не так? спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы выводите значение элемента массива после инкремента переменной `i`, вследствие чего выводятся элементы массива с индексами [1..4], вместо желаемых [0..3]. Поменяйте местами две последних строки цикла.